# Removing boilerplate attributes from resources

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In chef, each resource is defined like this:

```
directory "/home/akihiro/folder" do
  owner "akihiro"
  group "akihiro"
  mode 0755
end
```

If this is the only task under `akihiro`'s home directory, that's fine.

Unfortunately, I have to create directories, copy files, and apply templates, all under the same home directory as the owner.  Therefore `owner "akihiro"; group "akihiro"` must be set on every resource, which is very redundant.

If the resource could be written like this,

```
directory "/home/akihiro/folder" do
  as_akihiro
  mode 0755
end
```

where `as_akihiro` is defined somewhere outside the resource, the recipe would get much clearer.

Is it possible to remove the boilerplate attributes by defining a new method?

Comment: I think you would get a faster answer if you just tried it than asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here.

### Rubyish

You can create a Ruby module that defines this method:

```
module Impersonator
  def as(person, perms = '0755')
    send(:owner, person)
    send(:group, person)
    send(:mode,  perms)
  end
end
```

And then include this module in the resource:

```
Chef::Resource.send(:include, Impersonator)
```

And then use it:

```
directory '/foo/bar' do
  as 'akihiro' # or as 'akihiro', '0644'
end
```

---

### Chefish

If I understand your use case correct, the preferred way to handle this is with an [LWRP](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html) (or HWRP). You indicated this process occurs multiple times and wraps core Chef resources. This is a great use case for an LWRP. Essentially you wrap and parameterize all of these resources into a single "wrapper".

```
# providers/default.rb
action :run do
  user new_resource.username do
    # ...
  end

  directory "/home/#{new_resource.username}" do
    owner new_resource.username
    group new_resource.group
    mode  new_resource.mode
  end

  # Other resources, using the `new_resource` object
end
```

And then in a Chef recipe, you would use this resource (assuming it is named "company_user"):

```
company_user 'akihiro'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is possible. What works for me is to open the class that implements the "directory" resource, Chef::Resource::Directory and add a method as_akihiro. To do so, add a library to *your_cookbook*/libraries/as_user_helper.rb

```
class Chef::Resource::Directory
def as_akihiro()
    owner "akihiro"
    group "akihiro"
end
```

and you're done.